# i want to call a phone number from the simulator

Tags: iphone

i have a phone number in my array and i want to press call button and number should be called so how it happen in simulator..i am new in this field.

Comment: The Simulator doesn't have a SIM card does it :)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot make a call from the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator cannot place calls.

Comment: Make an app that responds to the tel protocol. It should get you close to what conceptually happens.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone Simulator doesn't support Calling feature.To ensure that your app is working properly(making calls) you will have to test it on the device only,that too on iPhone only.